# Unable to figure out CSS classes

Tags: html, css

I'm going through a coldfusion file (cfm) and figuring out where exactly the classes are defined:

For example, in my code I have something like the following:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td class="leftsidebar">
        <div class="title1 center">Some Text</div>
        <div class="title2 center">Some Text</div>
        <div class="leftmenu">
            Some Code here
        </div>
    </td>
```

The coldfusion file in which the above code is written doesn't contain classes like "leftsidebar",

title1, center , rightsidebar etc.

I have some  tags defined too followingthe aforementioned code, for example:

```
<div id="somename" class="clear">
    <label>Description
        <!--- <span class="small">Say something...</span> --->
    </label>
    <textarea 
        name="somename" 
        id="someid" 
        class="ui-corner-all" 
        rows="4"
    >
        YYY
    </textarea>  

</div>
```

In above code also, classes like clear , ui-corner-all are defined which I'm unable to figure out where exactly they are defined.

Comment: Is there an external stylesheet?

Comment: some of the classes might be defined with the use of jQuery

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI? ui-corner sounds like something coming from jQuery UI.

Comment: You can use Firebug or similar dev tools to trace CSS styles and classes.

Comment: To be clear, it's not just that these classes are there but that they have styles being applied to them, correct?

Comment: Oh, yes, j-Query is used. Perhaps, I should use Firebug and figure out what's going on here. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: Classes do not need to be defined, and are not exclusively the realm of CSS.  (You _can_ apply styling to classes with CSS, but this is not a requirement. A class can be used by JavaScript, or it might simply be placed to provide semantic information for anyone who happens to parse the script, such as via browser plugins, server-side scripts, or whatever.)